# Convert a Google Earth kml to a Google maps kml - Using image overlays

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created a kml file with Google Earth that creates an overlay using an external image. It works well, and I would like to find a reasonably convenient way of converting the kml so that Google Maps can read it and display it in a similar fashion.

Google Maps cannot process Google Earth coordinates, so I attempted to convert them myself. For instance I replaced the Earth Coordinates:

```
<gx:LatLonQuad>
<coordinates>
-80.34344837780532,33.1105864538138,0 
-80.31934785561177,33.09410014458361,0 
-80.30034967982111,33.11373571527255,0 
-80.32473786478347,33.13044135685429,0 
</coordinates>
</gx:LatLonQuad>
```

with the equivalent Maps coordinates:

```
<LatLonBox>
<north>33.13044135685429</north>
<south>33.11373571527255</south>
<east>-80.31934785561177</east>
<west>-80.34344837780532</west>
</LatLonBox>
```

Unfortunately, the are not exactly "equivalent". The Maps overlay is slightly off and rotated incorrectly.

Here are the images from the two:

**Earth Example**

[image]

**Maps Example**

[image]

I can see why it doesn't work, but I'm at a loss as to another solution. Anyone know of a simple way to convert a Google Earth kml to a Google Maps kml when an image overlay is involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#latlonbox) a `<LatLonBox>` also has a rotation.  Not sure if that is supported for Google Maps, but it should address the issue you are having.  The `<gx:LatLonQuad>` allows you do specify a rotated box (which is what you are doing), this is what that specifies:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/GoogleEarthPolygon.kml

According to the [KML reference for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps), LatLonBox is supported, rotation is not:

```
 KML Element    Supported in Google Maps? 
 <LatLonBox>    yes
 <rotation>     no
```

therefore you need to make your overlay align on north/south east/west boundaries (a non-rotated LatLonBox) to work on Google Maps.

You have a problem with your computed LatLonBox (the small blue box), you want the green box:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/GoogleEarthPolygonA.kml

I think the only way to fix this is to take your original image rotate it and save an image aligned on north/south east/west boundaries that fits in the bigger box.

Either that or make a custom overlay that supports rotation somehow.

Comment: The rotation tag does not work in Google maps as far as I have tested, and neither does the <gx:LatLonQuad>. They are both ignored, and that's why I was attempting to use the <LatLonBox> tags instead.